# What happens if I train a large deep learning model using a graphics card with insufficient VRAM?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, hardware

This is just a general question rather than a specific issue.

For an upcoming school assignment I'll need to use OpenCV. From what the professor told me an OpenCV model can take up to 8GB memory, but my graphics card (GTX 960) has only 2GB of VRAM. What will happen if I try training a model larger than 2GB? Can Tensorflow make use of my CPU memory to store the model?

Answer (score 0):

CV2 is typically used to do some processing on images, like reading them in or resizing them. The model is independent of cv2 except where cv2 is used to input and preprocess the images and prepare them as an input to the model. The amount of memory you will use depends on the image sizes and on the model you build. To avoid requiring a lot of memory you typically do not want to put all your images into memory at once but instead process them in batches. Keras provides an number of ways to do that. Documentation for that is located [here.](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/)